# Regex to enter a decimal number digit by digit

Tags: regex

I have a requirement where user can input only between 0.01 to 100.00 in a textbox. I am using regex to limit the data entered. However, I cannot enter a decimal point, like 95.83 in the regex. Can someone help me fix the below regex?

```
(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$
```

if I copy paste the value, it passes. But unable to type a decimal point.

Please advice.

Link to regex tester: https://regex101.com/r/b2BF6A/1

Link to demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9h2xsy

Comment: What do you consider a *valid* decimal. Of the following, which are valid: `.1`, `1.`, or strictly `0.0` format?

Comment: .1 0.1 0.01 -> 2 decimal places and the lowest value is 0.01 and highest is 100.00 The entered value should pass the regex if it falls within this range

Comment: One possible solution: `^(?:(?!0*\.?0+$)\d{0,2}\.?\d{1,2}|10{2}\.0{2})$` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/b2BF6A/2)

Comment: Fails when I type in 89(dot)

Comment: Yes, because you didn't specify that as a possible format in your last comment.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: Using an upper limit of 100.00 is a nuisance; it probably requires a special case.  An upper limit of 99.99 would be easier (or a non-inclusive upper bound of 100.00).

Comment: What do you consider a *valid* decimal: ending in dot `1.`, starting with dot `.1`
, or only numbers that contain a dot, but neither start nor finish with a dot `1.1` - sorry, should have made it more clear in my initial comment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I need a usecase for 100.00 as well. If teh user enter 100.01, the regex should fail

Comment: And, related is 09.90 OK?  The leading zero?  The trailing zero?  Is 099.99 OK?  More leading zeros than just the one?  Is 100 OK?  100.? 100.0? 100.00? 100.000?

Comment: Nope. Just two or three digits before the decimal, lowest can be 00.01 and highest can be 100.00 considering 00. and 100.

Comment: @a2441918 What about `0.01111111111111111111`?

Comment: Nope. Only 0.01, max is two decimal places

Comment: Then `^(?:(?!0*\.?0+$)\d{0,2}\.?\d{1,2}|10{2}\.0{2})$` should work for you

Comment: I type in 10(dot) and it fails buddy. It should pass 10(dot)

Comment: @ctwheels This is a mockup: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9h2xsy

Comment: Then you want [this](https://regex101.com/r/b2BF6A/3): `^(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|\d[1-9])(?:\.\d{0,2})?|(?:\d{0,2}\.)?(?:[1-9]\d?|\d[1-9])|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$`

Comment: I can enter 1000 here

Comment: No you can't you magician

Comment: @ctwheels Check this link please. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vht1bg I have your regex here. Try entering 1000 and more 0's

Comment: @a2441918 change it to `/^(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|\d[1-9])(?:\.\d{0,2})?|(?:\d{0,2}\.)?(?:[1-9]\d?|\d[1-9])|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$/` instead of calling RegExp or escape backslashes

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/b2BF6A/4) is the shortest and most concise I could make `^((?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)(?:\.\d{0,2})?|(?:0{0,2}\.)?(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$`

Comment: Thanks buddy. When I try to clear, why does the regex prevent clearing data? Can we add a case for empty string as well?

Comment: @a2441918 yes, my answer provides full details for this - currently accepted answer fails to properly validate a number of strings that you specified it should: `.1`, `00.01`, `09.90`, `01.`, `01.11`, `00.1`, etc.

Comment: Modded the regex to handle `.1, 00.01, 09.90, 01., 01.11, 00.1, ` as well, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the range 0.01 to 100.00 without padding is this (non-factored):

`0\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d)|[1-9]\d?\.\d{2}|100\.00`

Expanded

```
                                 #  0.01  to  0.99
   0 \. 
   (?:
        0 [1-9] 
     |  [1-9] \d 
   )
|  
                                 #  1.00  to  99.99
   [1-9] \d? \. 
   \d{2} 
|  
                                 #  100.00
   100 \. 
   00
```

---

It can be made to have an optional cascade if incremental partial form
should be allowed.

That partial is shown here for the top regex range :

`^(?:0(?:\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\d?)?)?|[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$`

The code line with stringed regex :

```
const newRegExp = new RegExp("^(?:0(?:\\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\\d?)?)?|[1-9]\\d?(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$");
```

**_________________________**

The regex 'partial' above requires the input to be blank or to start
with a digit. It also doesn't allow 1-9 with a preceding 0.

If that is all to be allowed, a simple mod is this :

`^(?:0{0,2}(?:\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\d?)?)?|(?:[1-9]\d?|0[1-9])(?:\.\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$`

which allows input like the following:

(*It should be noted that doing this requires allowing the dot . as

a valid input but could be converted to `0.` on the fly to be put

inside the input box.*)

```
.1
00.01
09.90
01.
01.11
00.1
00
.
```

Stringed version :

```
"^(?:0{0,2}(?:\\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\\d?)?)?|(?:[1-9]\\d?|0[1-9])(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$"
```

Comment: if I enter just 100, it fails

Comment: `It can be made to have an optional cascade if incremental partial form
should be allowed. But that is not shown here.` Is that something needed ?

Comment: Any idea why it doesnt support whole numbers? The range is from 0.01 to 100.00 including whole numbers, as well as 89(dot) and 100(dot)00

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is a mockup: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9h2xsy

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - That's just an option I use when generating ranges, you can turn it off if needed  Like use class only instead.  http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/MegNrange.jpg

Comment: @a2441918 - How did that regex in the comment work, try it yet ?

Comment: Works almost, but I cannot enter a 0 and if i clear the input, doesnt clear the last digit available. Please replace the regex here and try it https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9h2xsy

Comment: Much more relevant than a regex test framework is a specification — a series of values to be accepted, including variations on a theme, and a series of values to be rejected (including variations on a theme again).  So, OK might list `100`, `100.`, `100.0`, `100.00` and Not OK might list `0100`, `100.000`, `100.01` — and so on.  Is `000.00` valid or invalid?  It is invalid in JSON (only a single leading zero is allowed) but valid in C.  What about `0`, `0.`, `.0`, `.00`, `.000`, `0.0`, `0.00`, `00.0`, `00.`, etc.

Comment: @a2441918 - Ok, the issue is fixed with this. However while this regex matches the decimal, etc.. your program doesn't allow the dot charactter as input. `^(?:0(?:\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\d?)?)?|[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$`

Comment: Yeah the regex should allow

Comment: It has to do with escape characters, either change each backslash to two or drop using `RegExp` and use `/pattern/` instead.

Comment: He's right (@ctwheels) I used `"^(?:0(?:\\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\\d?)?)?|[1-9]\\d?(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$"` and it all works now. Code line `const newRegExp = new RegExp("^(?:0(?:\\.(?:(?:0[1-9]?)|[1-9]\\d?)?)?|[1-9]\\d?(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?|1(?:0(?:0(?:\\.0{0,2})?)?)?)?$");`

Answer (score 2):

## The regex

You can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/b2BF6A/6)

```
^(?:(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)(?:\.\d{0,2})?|0{0,2}\.(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$
```

---

#### How it works

- `^(?:...|...|...)$` this anchors the pattern to ensure it matches the entire string

  - `^` assert position at the start of the line
  - `(?:...|...|...)` non-capture group - used to group multiple alternations
  - `$` assert position at the end of the line
- `(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)(?:\.\d{0,2})?` first option

  - `(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)` match either of the following

    - `\d?[1-9]` optionally match any digit, then match a digit in the range of 1 to 9
    - `[1-9]0` match any digit between 1 and 9, followed by `0`
  - `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` optionally match the following

    - `\.` this character `.` literally
    - `\d{0,2}` match any digit between 0 and 2 times
- `0{0,2}\.(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)` second option

  - `0{0,2}` match `0` between 0 and 2 times
  - `\.` match this character `.` literally
  - `(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)` match either of the following options

    - `\d?[1-9]` optionally match any digit, then match a digit in the range of 1 to 9
    - `[1-9]0` match any digit between 1 and 9, followed by `0`
- `10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?` third option

  - `10{2}` match `100`
  - `(?:\.0{0,2})?` optionally match `.`, followed by `0` between 0 and 2 times

---

#### How it works (in simpler terms)

With the above descriptions for each alternation, this is what they will match:

1. Any two-digit number other than `0` or `00`, optionally followed by any two-digit decimal.

   - In terms of a range, it's `1.00-99.99` with:

     - Optional leading zero: `01.00-99.99`
     - Optional decimal: `01-99`, or `01.-99`, or `01.0-01.99`
2. Any two-digit decimal other than `0` or `00`

   - In terms of a range, it's `.01-.99` with:

     - Optional leading zeroes: `00.01-00.99` or `0.01-0.99`
3. Literally `100`, followed by optional decimals: `100`, or `100.`, or `100.0`, or `100.00`

---

## The code

#### RegExp vs `/pattern/`

In your code, you can use either of the following options (replacing `pattern` with the pattern above):

```
new RegExp('pattern')
/pattern/
```

The first option above uses a string literal. This means that you must escape the backslash characters in the string in order for the pattern to be properly read:

```
^(?:(?:\\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?|0{0,2}\\.(?:\\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)|10{2}(?:\\.0{0,2})?)$
```

The second option above allows you to avoid this and use the regex as is.

[Here's a fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9dy8np) of your code using the second option.

---

#### Usability Issues

Please note that you'll run into a couple of usability issues with your current method of tackling this:

- The user cannot erase all the digits they've entered. So if the user enters `100`, they can only erase `00` and the `1` will remain. One option to *resolving* this is to make the entire non-capture group (with the alternations) optional by adding a `?` after it. Whilst this does solve that issue, you now need to keep two regular expression patterns - one for user input and the other for validation. Alternatively, you could just test if the input is an empty string to allow it (but not validate the form until the field is filled.
- The user cannot enter a number beginning with `.`. This is because we don't allow the input of `.` to go through your validation steps. The same rule applies here as the previous point made. You can allow it though if the value is `.` explicitly or add a new alternation of `|\.`
- Similarly to my last point, you'll run into the issue for `.0` when a user is trying to write something like `.01`. Again here, you can run the same test.
- Similarly again, `0` is not valid input - same applies here.

An change to the regex that covers these states (`0`, `.`, `.0`, `0.`, `0.0`, `00.0` - but not `.00` alternatives) is:

```
^(?:(?:\d?[1-9]?|[1-9]0)(?:\.\d{0,2})?|0{0,2}\.(?:\d?[1-9]?|[1-9]0)|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$
```

Better would be to create logic for these cases to match them with a separate regex:

```
^0{0,2}\.?0?$
```

---

#### Usability Fixes

With the changes above in mind, your function would become:

[See code fork here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slgi2b)

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  const r1 = /^(?:(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)(?:\.\d{0,2})?|0{0,2}\.(?:\d?[1-9]|[1-9]0)|10{2}(?:\.0{0,2})?)$/;
  const r2 = /^0{0,2}\.?0?$/
  if (r1.test(e.target.value)) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  } else if (r2.test(e.target.value)) {
    // Value is invalid, but permitted for usability purposes
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
}
```

This now allows the user to input those values, but also allows us to invalidate them if the user tries to submit it.